# autocomplete textbox within jqgrid shows error, item is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, autocomplete

One of the columns in a jqgrid Grid contains a autocomplete textbox during the edit mode.
The autocomplete is wired correctly with the ajax call to get the data for autocomplete.

When an item from the autcomplete list is selected using the mouse, the selection works correctly with no errors thrown.
However when i use keyboard down arrow to select an item and then press enter key, the item does not get selected and infact the jquery.ui plugin for autocomplete throws an error, stating item is undefined.

The problem here is that both the jqgrid edit complete event and and autocomplete select event are listening to the enter key and the jqgrid edit complete event fires before the jquery.ui autocomplete's select event and hence the edit cell is closed for editing and the select event of jquery.ui autocomplete plugin does not receive the selected item and hence we get the error item is undefined.

Can anyone suggest as to how to ensure that both the edit complete event and the autocomplete events COMPLETE successfully without the short circuit that is currently happening with the jqgrid's edit complete event.????

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the most simply way will be **unbind** `keydown` (calls `.unbind("keydown")`) inside of `dataInit` **before** you  call `autocomplete`. You should manage yourself <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> key pressing to force discarding or saving of editing.

Comment: Actually I want to do gridcell.unbind("keydown"). But in the dataInit function I am not able to get a reference to the gridCell. How do I get a reference to the gridCell???

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the following code in afterCellEdit Event :

```
     var cellDOM = this.rows[iRow].cells[iCol], oldKeydown,
     $cellInput = $('input, select, textarea', cellDOM),oldKeydown,
        events = $cellInput.data('events');
    if (events && events.keydown && events.keydown.length) {
        oldKeydown = events.keydown[0].handler;
        $cellInput.unbind('keydown', oldKeydown);
        $cellInput.bind('keydown', function (e) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                oldKeydown.call(this, e);
            }, 100);
        });
    }
};
```

Essentially I added a delay to the KeyDown handler of the cell, so that It fires after about 100 milliseconds, this allowed the AutoComplete select event to receive the item and this complete its "select" event successfully.